# Resize whole window elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm looking for a way to resize the whole window of my webpage to fit the window size.
So, kind of [this](http://css-tricks.com/examples/FullPageBackgroundImage/progressive.php) (look at the background image). But for the whole page?

And I'm not talking about keeping the font the same size, or the images. I'm really talking about resizing everything in the screen. So even the images would resize.

Comment: You would want to use percentages in your CSS.

Comment: Percentage on everything? Is there a jQuery alternative where it would resize everything without having to change all the CSS?

Comment: You could look at jQuery's `.resize()` method.

Comment: I have found this : http://www.ollicle.com/projects/jquery/imagefit/eg/ ...But can't get it to work. Do you have examples of how to use .resize() ? I've looked on the jQuery website but I'd like to see actual demo?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/2ZckV/ here's an example. If you change the width of the bottom right pane, the image of the puppy will expand to fit the inner width of the page.

Comment: Perfect, that's what I was looking for. But when I try it in my website, it does not work. The images are not resizing. Isn't that supposed to be applied to all "img" tags?

Comment: It's working in JS Fiddle, but not when I try it in my html file...weird? Here's the exact code I use : http://jsfiddle.net/ffYy6/ ...it's working. but not else where than JSFiddle